# Teamcity NUnit fails when using JetBrains dotCover

Tags: nunit, teamcity, dotcover

My build fails with this log:

```
[12:13:40]: Checking for changes
[12:13:41]: Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[12:13:41]: Checkout directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\9fecf8ffe0e03cce
[12:13:41]: Updating sources: server side checkout...
[12:13:41]: Publishing internal artifacts (4s)
[12:13:41]: Step 1/3: Visual Studio (sln) (17s)
[12:13:58]: Step 2/3: NUnit (19s)
[12:13:58]: Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe #TeamCityImplicit
[12:13:58]: in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\9fecf8ffe0e03cce
[12:14:02]: JetBrains dotCover Console Runner v1.1.252.2. Copyright (c) 2009-2011 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.
[12:14:05]: Coverage session started [18.8.2011 12:14:05]
[12:14:09]: Start TeamCity NUnit Test Runner
[12:14:09]: Running NUnit-2.5.10 tests under .NET Framework v2.0 x86
[12:14:10]: MySolution.Communication.Tests.dll
[12:14:10]: MySolution.Communication.Tests.TestClass.CanUseGetRequestPacket
[12:14:18]: Coverage session finished [18.8.2011 12:14:18]
[12:14:18]: Analysed application exited with code '255'
[12:14:18]: Coverage session finished but no snapshots were created. 
[12:14:18]: Process exited with code -2
[12:14:18]: Step NUnit failed
[12:14:18]: Build step Duplicates finder (.NET) skipped because of previous step failure
[12:14:18]: Publishing internal artifacts
[12:14:18]: Build finished
```

I am using Teamcity Professional 6.5.2, NUnit-2.5.10 v2.0 MSIL and build-in JetBrains dotCover. Without JetBrains dotCover all is ok. At another project I am using same configuration and all is ok as well. Could be here some problem with my tests assembly?

Comment: take a look at the Fuul Build Log in teamcity, try to search throug for "exception", "failure" words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dotCover fails with obfuscated assemblies.

Comment: This seems like it could be a key to the solution. How do I know whether the assemblies are obfuscated or not? How do I prevent obfuscation? And as an aside, is this behaviour documented anywhere?